# On the google app engine, how do I get rid of the 'Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions' error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pydev

I am having trouble with one specific query. It needs to run in a transaction, and it does, but whenever the app engine executes my query I get the following error:

> Only ancestor queries are allowed
>   inside transactions

You'll see that my query DOES have an ancestor. So what is the app engine really complaining about?

```
    q = db.Query(EventBase)
    q.ancestor = db.Key.from_path(aggrRootKind, aggrRootKeyName)
    q.filter('undone =','False')
    q.order('-version')
    qResult = q.fetch(1, 0)
```

Comment: Can you show a bit more of the code: are you doing anything else inside the transaction that might be accessing a different entity group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
q.ancestor = db.Key.from_path(aggrRootKind, aggrRootKeyName)
```

should read:

```
q.ancestor(db.Key.from_path(aggrRootKind, aggrRootKeyName))
```

ancestor() is a method, and in the first snippet, you're replacing it, rather than calling it.

Comment: ARG, silly me. I keep doing that. Thanks for pointing out my mistake :)